# How to specify covariates in a regression model

Tags: r, regression

The dataset I would like to analyse looks like this

```
n <- 4000
tmp <- t(replicate(n, sample(49,6)))
dat <- matrix(0, nrow=n, ncol=49)
colnames(dat) <- paste("p", 1:49, sep="")
dat <- as.data.frame(dat)
dat[, "win.frac"] <- rnorm(n, mean=0.0176504, sd=0.002)
for (i in 1:nrow(dat)) 
  for (j in 1:6) dat[i, paste("p", tmp[i, j], sep="")] <- 1
str(dat)
```

Now I would like to perform a regression with depended variable `win.frac` and all other variables (`p1`, ..., `p49`) as explanatory variables.

However, with all approaches I tried I get the coefficient for `p49` as NA, with the message "1 not defined because of singularities". I tried

```
modspec <- paste("win.frac ~", paste("p", 1:49, sep="", collapse=" + "))
fit1 <- lm(as.formula(modspec), data=dat)
fit2 <- lm(win.frac ~ ., data=dat)
```

Interestingly, the regression works if I use 48 explanatory variables. This may (p2, ..., p49) or may not (p1, ..., p48) contain the p49, hence I think this
is not related to the variable p49 itself. I also tried larger values of `n`, with the same result.

I also tried `betareg` from the `betareg` package, since `win.frac` is restricted between 0 and 1. The regression in this case fails too, with the error message (roughly translated) "error in optim(...): non-finite value of optim specified"

```
library(betareg)
fit3 <- betareg(as.formula(modspec), data=dat, link="log")
```

Now I am stuck. How can I perform this regression? Is there a maximum of variables? Is this problem due to the fact that the explanatory variables are either 0 or 1?

Any hint is very appreciated!

Comment: All of your covariates sum to 6. `rowSums(dat[,-50])`. That means if you know 48 of the 49, you know what the last value it. This means you have linear dependence among your predictors. You cannot fit estimate every parameter in this situations. Really, this is question for [stats.se] because this problem is statistical in nature; it's not a programming problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that those are dummy encoded factor variables.

If you do the following you can see that you get a perfect fit if you try to model one of your regressors with all others:

```
regressormod <- lm(p49 ~ . - win.frac, data = dat)
summary(regressormod)$r.sq
#[1] 1
```

It's (mathematically) impossible to include all coeffcients from dummy-encoded factor variables in a regression model that also includes an intercept ([see this answer on Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/70700/11849)). That's why R excludes one factor level by default if you let it do the dummy encoding for you.

Comment: Very helpful, in particular the link to the discussion on cross validated. Thank you! I learned a lot today.