# Possible to use (y,X) in a model instead of y~x1+x2... in R?

Tags: r, statistics

I'm porting some of the stuff I've done in python over to R and a lot of my models in scikit use this type of formula. It's helpful in my use case because the dataframe's I work with typically have many variables/features. In R most guide's suggest building a model using a formula such as

```
lm(y~x1+x2+x3...)
```

If I do this with a high dimensional dataframe it gets messy quickly. I've figured out how to build a formula with many variables like this

```
form <- as.formula(paste0('~', paste(names(df), collapse='+')
```

I concat this with y to create the full formula. Is it possible to just supply a model with a response variable vector and a matrix of predictors similar to the following?

```
lm(y,X) or lm(y~X)
```

Comment: if you have a matrix or a data set just use `y ~ .` where that `.` stands for *all other variables*.

Comment: Oh ok, perfect. Thank you!

Comment: Yes, Exactly. Try it with the `mtcars` data set built in R. fit a model like `lm(qsec ~ . , data =  mtcars)`

Comment: Have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30937674/how-to-specify-covariates-in-a-regression-model/30938164#30938164) and next time please do search for questions because often (like this time) answers already exist.

Comment: you can also remove variables by name say you wanted a model of all variables except `z` , you could do `lm(y ~ . -z)`